# SQLServer: Dynamic sql raise exception Could not find stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql

This is my dynamic sql.

```
DECLARE @SQL varchar(MAX)
DECLARE @Data varchar(MAX)
SET @Data='ALFKI'' OR ContactName=''Ana Trujillo'''
SET @SQL='select * from Customers Where CustomerID='''+@Data+''

print @SQL
exec (@SQL)
```

when i print then i get this `sql select * from Customers Where CustomerID='ALFKI'` this sql is right one but when i replace `print @SQL` with `exec @SQL` and execute the dynamic sql again then i am getting error called

> Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 8 Could not find stored procedure
>   'select * from Customers Where CustomerID='ALFKI''.

not clear where i made the mistake. please give me some hint where is the problem in above dynamic sql. thanks

Comment: Why you need a dynamic sql for such a simple query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is `EXEC` to execute a stored procedure. Of course there is no SP with the name `select * from Customers...`.

And there is `EXEC()`, a function!, which is used to execute dynamically created statements.

Just use `EXEC(@SQL)` instead.

Another way with some more options is [`sp_executesql`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql) with wide support for parameters. You can use this to pass the `ALFKI` as parameter. Otherwise you might be open for SQL injection...